# Bogus.Faker: How to pick a random enum value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, bogus

I'm using c# **Bogus.Faker library** to create random test data for my unit tests.
I want to know how to easily pick a **random enum value** ?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Found the solution: 
 You have to use **Faker.PickRandom<>** method

```
i.TypeOfSchedule = Faker.PickRandom<Schedule>(); // with 'Schedule' of type Enum :-)
```